# Appcelerator failing to run Dexer with no error message

Tags: android, mobile, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I recently got a mac and followed the tutorial on Appcerelator's website to ensure I properly installed everything. When I build it for ios I do not have any issues at all. But, when building for Android I always get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to run dexer:
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]
```

The thing that is mostly throwing me off, is the lack of error messages unlike all of the other users with this issue.

I have tried lowering the max memory and most of the other things that I have came across. I also have a barebones program that does not include any packages or anything like that. So, it should not be an issue with two packages conflicting with each other.

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try lowering the log level and see if anything else pops up. Also, what is displayed above this line? The last thing happening is usually an indication where the issue is. Furthermore, what TiSDK/Alloy/CLI/ios etc version do you have

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers it ended up being, the previous owner of this Mac(work for a company who gives us laptops) changed all of the Java paths and it caused all of my issues.